# lineinfile query in ansible to replace or delete a string

Tags: ansible

While trying to install apache via ansible I am getting the error of libToolt hence my apr-util is not getting configured. I am trying to replace `$RM "cfgfile"` with `$RM -f "cfgfile"` in configure by using regexp it is either getting copied at the last or not working.

```
- name: Replace file
    path: file path
    regexp: '$RM -f "cfgfile"'
```

But the value that is going when I am trying to run my YAML file is
    `$RM\\\"$cfgfile\"`

Comment: In the future, you'll want to post meaningful debugging text, such as the output of running ansible-playbook, the error, the file you are trying to change, or anything in the known universe that could enable someone on SO to help you. Please read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page, and pay especial attention to the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) section

Answer (score 0):

You must escape the `$` in your `regexp` since that character is meaningful to regexp; or, skip the silliness and just use `line:` instead of `regexp:` since your text does not contain any variable parts (which is the circumstances under which one would use a regex)